# In magento change data-vocabulary to schema.org

Tags: magento-1.9

I received the mail from google saying Breadcrumbs issues detected

Warning : data-vocabulary.org schema deprecated

On research about these I came across that Starting April 6, 2020, Google will no longer support data-vocabulary.org structured data to enable rich results in Google Search. From January 20 until April 6, any data-vocabulary.org structured data on a web page will trigger a warning for the appropriate rich result type. After April 6, an error will be triggered.

My code

```
<li class="<?php echo $_crumbName ?>" <?php if($_crumbName == 'home'){ echo 'itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"'; }?>>
            <?php if($_crumbInfo['link']): ?>
                <a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $_crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['title']) ?>">
                <span itemprop="title" class="breadcrumb_title"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></span>
                </a>
            <?php elseif($_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
                <span itemprop="title">
                <strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>
                </span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if(!$_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
                <span>> </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
```

How can I change data-vocabulary to schema.org

Answer (score 2):

please update code with below code

```
<?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) : ?>
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <ul class="items">
            <?php $i = 0;?>
            <?php foreach ($crumbs as $_crumbName => $_crumbInfo) : ?>
                <?php $i++;?>
                <li class="<?php echo $_crumbName ?>" <?php if ($_crumbInfo['link']) {
                    echo 'itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList"';
                } ?>
                    >
                    <?php if ($_crumbInfo['link']): ?>
                        <span itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
                            <a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $_crumbInfo['link'] ?>"
                               title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['title']) ?>">
                                <span itemprop="name"
                                  class="breadcrumb_title"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></span>
                             </a>
                            <span itemprop="position" style="display: none"><?php echo $i?></span>
                        </span>

                    <?php elseif ($_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
                        <span itemprop="name">
                            <strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>
                        </span>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if (!$_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
                        <span>> </span>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

([source](https://meetanshi.com/blog/fix-data-vocabulary-org-schema-deprecated-error/))

Comment: This works, but on some products :
A value for the ratingValue field is required & One of ratingCount or reviewCount must be provided. This warning comes up on google search console

Comment: if you give me url to test than i solve it and update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue and solved it by replacing data-vocabulary schema by the schema.org schema.

Create an override of the current breadcrumbs.phtml to your own theme (example)
app/design/frontend/example/default/template/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml

### my implementation

```
<?php if($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)): ?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
        <?php $_i = 1; ?>
        <?php foreach($crumbs as $_crumbName=>$_crumbInfo): ?>
            <li class="<?php echo $_crumbName ?>" itemprop="itemListelement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
            <?php if($_crumbInfo['link']): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $_crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['title']) ?>" itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></span></a>
            <?php elseif($_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['title']) ?>" itemprop="item"><span class="last-crumb" aria-current="page" itemprop="name"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></span></a>
            <?php else: ?>
                    <span itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></span></span>
            <?php endif; ?> 
                <meta itemprop="position" content="<?php echo $_i; ?>">
                </li>
        <?php $_i++; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Issue has been solved on Magento v1.9

Answer (score 0):

Structured data schema such as schema.org and data-vocabulary.org are used to define shared meaningful structures for markup-based applications on the Web.

With the increasing usage and popularity of schema.org we decided to focus our development on a single SD scheme.
SIMPLE & SHORT meaning: - Google stopped to use the data-vocabulary markups [aka RDFa] - So, we need to change our websites to Schema.org markups.

Ref: https://vvcares.com/blog/post/data-vocabulary-schema-deprecated